# Ruby on rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I figured a way to do validation. I found that inside models, i need to add these lines

`validates_presence_of :name`
`validates_uniqueness_of :name`

**What i'm trying to achieve** is for example, i don't want the user to add `:;!@#$%^&*()` [or special characters] in my text inputs. Need some inputs on this.

Comment: Use the `:format` as described [in the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [format_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of):

```
validates_format_of :name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z]|\d)*\Z/
```

Or create your own validation:

```
validates :name,
   :presence   => true,
   :format     => { :with => regex } # Here you can set a 'regex'
```

Comment: That was totally quick. Thanks a ton.